# Inserting Data from JSON to SQLite Database with AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, json, database, sqlite

I am trying to put data to the database from JSON.
I have this code running in @doInBackground method:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


    HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();

    String url = "https://www...";


    String jsonStr = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(url);

    Log.e(TAG, "Response from URL: " + jsonStr);


    if (jsonStr != null) {


        try{


            JSONArray currencyItemsArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);


            JSONObject jsonCurrencyObject = currencyItemsArray.getJSONObject(1);

            String selling = jsonCurrencyObject.getString("selling");
            String code = jsonCurrencyObject.getString("code");

            CurrencyItems currencyItems = new CurrencyItems(code, selling);


            String codefromCI = currencyItems.getCode();
            double sellingfromCI = currencyItems.getSelling();

            String codefromCI = currencyItems.getCode();

            ContentValues currencyValues = new ContentValues();

            currencyValues.put(DBContract.CurrencyEntry.COLUMN_CODE, codefromCI);
            currencyValues.put(DBContract.CurrencyEntry.COLUMN_SELLING, sellingfromCI);

          // db.isOpen();

            db.insert(DBContract.CurrencyEntry.TABLE_NAME, null,
                    currencyValues);

            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: Inserted Successfully !" +
                    currencyValues);

             } catch (JSONException e){

            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }return null;

}
```

When I debug, I get the value until "currencyvalues.put.." but when it comes to "db.insert" it shows null.

When I searched, I found some information that I have to open the database first but it did not work.

What could be the solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have to extend `SQLiteOpenHelper` and use it's method `SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase()` to be able to write to `SQLite` database.

Comment: Yes, but I already extend AsyncTask. So I did this: mSQLiteDatabasefromDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();  but does not seem like working

Comment: It is wrong. You have create `class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` Make a search on Google or StackOverflow for words "extends SQLiteOpenHelper". Or read Android manual for this theme.